# Should we not use HTML5 offline Manifest on iphone because of cache size is very limited?

Tags: html, mobile-safari, mobile-website, offline-caching, offline-browsing

Should we not use HTML5 offline Manifest on iphone because of cache size is very limited? I don't exactly about Android browser.

I'v a simple Mobile website with 20-25 pages which I would like to make it work offline too. This site has Images, CSS, Javascrpt, HTML output, one audio file of 100kb. so total size of website is around 3mb.

As i read iphone safari has only 5MB space reserved for cache which is very low. And even I use manifest to cache some files but if user has already surfed some other websites which were using Manifest too and it filled 5MB cache then even will browser take my app's files in cache?

A good link related to this http://techblog.viewbook.com/2011/02/mobile-safari-offline-application-cache-limit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use it.

5MB is the standard storage size available to offline apps provided by browsers, it is not unusual, 5MB is the level set by the HTML5 standard.

The vast majority of offline capable apps will fit within 5MB, not-forgetting theres a WebSQL databases if you need to store there too.

Remember, the offline storage is for offline *apps*, not the caching of *entire websites* for the sake of it.

Typically, an offline app will comprise only of a couple of actual HTML pages, with the rest being generated by JavaScript through the logic of the application.

Answer (score 1):

If other websites are using the application cache, they will get their own 5Mb to use.  Different sites don't share appcache data.

Comment: So how much is total space in iphone 4 for all website?

Comment: @JitendraVyas From the point of view of your web app, why does it matter?  I expect it'll vary depending on how much storage there is available on the device.

Comment: So the Cache Manifest is applicable for mobile websites (besides mobile application)?